# Logic operations implementation

Tags: assembly, binary

I have this binary number
This is 32 bit binary number
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xxxx yyyy 
Every 0000 let's call a "nibble" .
Thus I have the words:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Now
I want to check whether in the last bit of 6th word I have 1 or 0

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 xxxx yyyy or 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xxxx yyyy

If I have 1 I want to obtain from given 32 bit binary number this number
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
otherwise 
I want to obtain this number
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
How to do it???
Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: Just FYI, groups of 4 bits are called "nibbles".

Comment: What processor you are targeting?

Comment: I want to understand how matematically to perform it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, `-(x >> 8)`
First shift the bit down to LSB (mask the rest if they may be non-zero). You now have `1` or `0`. Knowing that `-1` in 2's complement is all `1` bits, you just have to negate the value (note this isn't bitwise negation).

Comment: "negate the value " what do you mean?

Comment: You know, 2's complement arithmetic negation. Negative numbers? The `-` operator? If you don't have that, you can do bitwise negation and add one.

Comment: The problem is that I want to do the same operations and it one case obtain all 0's in other obtain all ones. I have 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 xxxx yyyy, after (>>8) I obtain 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001; I negate, and add 1 then i obtain all 1's

Comment: but if I have 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xxxx yyy,how to perform the same operations and remain the value?

Comment: What's your problem? If you shift `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xxxx yyy` you obtain all `0`, if you bitwise negate it's all `1`, if you add `1` you get back all `0`. That's what you want, isn't it.

Comment: :) I don't understand something) Yes, if I shift 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xxxx yyy I obtain all 0's. If I bitwise negate it its all 1's, 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111, if I add 1 it is 1  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000. Of course the leading one is lost.That is what you mean?